# How can I send a series of hex commands out of a COM port using a Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, serial-port

So far I have a batch file with the following contents...

```
MODE COM1:19,n,8,1
copy off.hex \\.\com1 /b
```

The contents of off.hex is where I am stuck.
I need the code shown below inside that file.

[image: rs232_codes]

Comment: I was able to create these files a few years ago and had it working. Unfortunately, I accidentally deleted them and I'm having trouble remembering how I did it the first time.

Comment: Not sure I understand...You want to create a hex file with the values in the picture (i.e. fir off operation)- but as their binary equivalents or as a string?

Comment: the `/b` options suggest a binary?

Comment: the image has the codes in hex format, but the file would be binary I think

Comment: The task is turning a projector on or off with shortcuts on the desktop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Totally not sure what the task is .If you want to get binaries may be this will help you:

```
@echo off
echo BEEF100500C6FF111101000100>off.txt
echo BEEF030600DCDB690000000000>on.txt

certutil -decodehex off.txt off.bin
certutil -decodehex on.txt on.bin

MODE COM1:19,n,8,1
copy off.bin \\.\com1 /b
copy on.bin \\.\com1 /b
```

Here's more info about [CERTUTIL](http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1562)
If you are running XP without CERTUTIL check [this](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-genchr.html)

Comment: The task is turning a projector on or off with shortcuts on the desktop.

Comment: No mater how many times I beat my head against the wall, I could not remember how I created those files a few years ago. Still can't. certutil did the trick perfectly, didn't even know it existed. I tried using a few hex editors, but that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Once upon a time, you might have used `DEBUG` to do this. I don't think `DEBUG` is available at all to 64-bit Windows, and may not ever have been in `CMD.EXE`. It was a feature of DOS and `COMMAND.COM` that allowed `.COM` format 16-bit programs to be debugged and modified by direct entry of either opcodes or HEX.

Comment: For some reason, I think I used Notepad++, but I didn't have any luck with that this time around